# Clock - "do stuff", wait 1sec, turned off "stuff" in python

Tags: python, timer, clock, countdown

I am trying to create a simple loop that checks if a certain key was pressed. If so, a line which highlights a certain object is turned on. I want that line to be turned on for just second or even less - it's only for the purpose of response feedback, let the user know that he chose what he intended to before moving in.

I was trying to play with it but couldn't make it work as the line either continued to be there or wasn't activated at all.

I first define border:

```
border = visual.ShapeStim(win, vertices=iimage.verticesPix, units='pix', lineWidth=5, lineColor='red')
border_1 = visual.ShapeStim(win, vertices=image_2.verticesPix, units='pix', lineWidth=5, lineColor='green')

if key_resp_2.keys=='left':
    border.autoDraw=True
    timer=core.CountDownTimer(1)
    while timer.getTime()<0
        border.autoDraw=False

if key_resp_2.keys=='right':
    border_1.autoDraw=True
    timer=core.CountdownTimer(2)
    while timer.getTime()<0:
        border.autoDraw=False
```

Comment: You're code is critically incomplete.  You aren't showing us what sort of GUI/toolkit you're using (Tkinter?, WxPython?, PyGame/PySDL?) ... thus we can't suggest what sort of ".update()" or ".redraw()" method you might have to call in your framework to trigger synchronization of the "canvas" to the actual screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
#do stuff
time.sleep(1) #or whatever
#do stuff
```

Comment: I tried to insert it inside my "if" loop, but the highlighted line wasn't created and everything just took 1sec more. import time

if key_resp_2.keys=='left':
    border.autoDraw=True
    time.sleep(1)
    border.autoDraw=False